# how to combine epoch time (e.g#214235235) and commad from .bash_history file and save it in one line.it should only display command with epoch time

Tags: awk, sed, grep

e.g (.bash_history file)

```
cd Fortigate_Report/
ll
exit
#1512031841
history>set1
#1512031849
history>set2
#1512031864
vi comm -23 <(sort set1) <(sort set2)
#1512031877
comm -23 <(sort set1) <(sort set2)
#1512031892
comm -23 <(sort set2) <(sort set1)
#1512031971
```

1. this should be copied in another file for eg(newfile.txt or any newfile)
2. the file should ignore the command which has no epoch time
3. and the  should ignore the epoch time which has no command

i.e newfile Output should be like this

```
#1512031841 history>set1 
#1512031849 history>set2
#1512031864 vi comm -23 <(sort set1) <(sort set2)
#1512031877 comm -23 <(sort set1) <(sort set2)
#1512031892 comm -23 <(sort set2) <(sort set1)
```

Answer (score 2):

With `sed`:

```
sed -n '/^#[0-9]\{1,\}$/N;s/\n/ /p' < file > newfile
```

Answer (score 1):

`testdata` will print your example data...

```
$ testdata() { cat<<dog                        
cd Fortigate_Report/
ll
exit
#1512031841
history>set1
#1512031849
history>set2
#1512031864
vi comm -23 <(sort set1) <(sort set2)
#1512031877
comm -23 <(sort set1) <(sort set2)
#1512031892
comm -23 <(sort set2) <(sort set1)
#1512031971
dog
}
```

...which then will be piped into `awk` which only reacts if seeing a timestamp. Then the next line will be read and and printed prefixed with the timestamp seen before:

```
$ testdata | awk '/^#/ && (getline L) > 0 { print $0, L }'
#1512031841 history>set1
#1512031849 history>set2
#1512031864 vi comm -23 <(sort set1) <(sort set2)
#1512031877 comm -23 <(sort set1) <(sort set2)
#1512031892 comm -23 <(sort set2) <(sort set1)
```